# PHP separate section

Tags: php

i have this text

> Desctiprion
>
> This premium executive plush office chair is well padded for comfort
> and support. Offering generous proportions, with recliner function,
> and features a head rest, curved and lightly padded arm rests, and
> classic button tufting to complete the look. The seat height is
> adjustable and the castors make it easy to maneuver. With a sturdy
> construction and stylish appeal, it is perfect for any executive
> office or home and offers adjustable gas lift, 360 degree swivel and
> luxurious leather-look style.
>
> Features:
>
> Comfortable, sturdy, and quality made  Adjustable recliner function
> Spacious design for long lasting comfort Soft and durable synthetic
> leather Padded chrome arms to help support your shoulders and upper
> body Strong and sturdy steel chrome base Large cushioning Gas Lift for
> Adjusting Height

Now i have function that get's all of this from website that i need to get it. Now i need to write function that it will separate Features section from Description. So i know that function need to recognize word 'Features', and get content under Features word, but how to write it?

Comment: Please Provide your coded attempts to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
private function getDescription($dom){

        $description = '';

        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $div){
            if($div->getAttribute('class') == 'productdetails'){

                $description = $div->nodeValue;
                $description = trim($description,"Features");
            }
        }
        return $description;
    }
```

I use DOM for scrapping website.  And this function give me output

> This premium executive plush office chair is well padded for comfort
>   and support. Offering generous proportions, with recliner function,
>   and features a head rest, curved and lightly padded arm rests, and
>   classic button tufting to complete the look. The seat height is
>   adjustable and the castors make it easy to maneuver. With a sturdy
>   construction and stylish appeal, it is perfect for any executive
>   office or home and offers adjustable gas lift, 360 degree swivel and
>   luxurious leather-look style. Features: Comfortable, sturdy, and
>   quality made  Adjustable recliner function Spacious design for long
>   lasting comfort Soft and durable synthetic leather Padded chrome arms
>   to help support your shoulders and upper body Strong and sturdy steel
>   chrome base Large cushioning Gas Lift for Adjusting Height

What is correct. Now i need to write code that didn't get content from Features. Because i need to write another function that will get that same content just from word Features.